# AttributeError when selecting 0s and 1s from MNIST dataset with PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, attributeerror, mnist

I am following a guide to build a model to classify between only 0s and 1s from the MNIST dataset. However, what they suggest to do to select 0/1 values is not working for my and raises an error.
This is the code I am using:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

mnist_train = datasets.MNIST("./data", train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
mnist_test = datasets.MNIST("./data", train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_idx = mnist_train.train_labels <= 1
mnist_train.train_data = mnist_train.train_data[train_idx]
mnist_train.train_labels = mnist_train.train_labels[train_idx]

test_idx = mnist_test.test_labels <= 1
mnist_test.test_data = mnist_test.test_data[test_idx]
mnist_test.test_labels = mnist_test.test_labels[test_idx]

train_loader = DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size = 100, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size = 100, shuffle=False)
```

And this is the output I get when I run it:

```
  File "<ipython-input-2-aa7f63047cd9>", line 8, in <module>
    mnist_train.train_data = mnist_train.train_data[train_idx]

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I also tried changing:

```
mnist_train.train_data = mnist_train.train_data[train_idx]
```

by:

```
try:
    mnist_train.train_data = mnist_train.train_data[train_idx]
except AttributeError:
    mnist_train._train_data = mnist_train.train_data[train_idx]
```

And adding that extra "_", in every statement of that kind seemed to solve the issue, but later on, when trying to train the model, I realized it had not selected only 0s and 1s. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to @ptrblck in a PyTorch forum(https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-use-one-class-of-number-in-mnist/26276/3):

With the latest PyTorch updates, the new syntax is:

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

mnist_train = datasets.MNIST("./data", train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
mnist_test = datasets.MNIST("./data", train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_idx = mnist_train.train_labels <= 1
mnist_train.data = mnist_train.train_data[train_idx]
mnist_train.targets = mnist_train.train_labels[train_idx]

test_idx = mnist_test.test_labels <= 1
mnist_test.data = mnist_test.test_data[test_idx]
mnist_test.targets = mnist_test.test_labels[test_idx]

train_loader = DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size = 100, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size = 100, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this in 2021, it seems `targets` should be always used instead of `train_labels`, so the best answer nowadays should be:

```py
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

mnist_train = datasets.MNIST("./data", train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
mnist_test = datasets.MNIST("./data", train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_idx = mnist_train.train_labels <= 1
mnist_train.data = mnist_train.data[train_idx]
mnist_train.targets = mnist_train.targets[train_idx]

test_idx = mnist_test.test_labels <= 1
mnist_test.data = mnist_test.data[test_idx]
mnist_test.targets = mnist_test.targets[test_idx]

train_loader = DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size = 100, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size = 100, shuffle=False)
```